# If $A^2 = I$, $B^2=I$ and $(AB)^2=I$, then $AB = BA$

Tags: matrices

Matrix Question

If $A^2 = I$, $B^2=I$ and $(AB)^2=I$, then $AB = BA$

Basically, got up to $A(BA-AB)B = 0$ (by cancelling and equating terms from $I^2 = I$ and to $A^2B^2 = A^2B^2$ and using distributive laws), but that doesn't work out too well!

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\color{#C00000}{BA}
&=AA(\color{#C00000}{BA})BB\\
&=\color{#00A000}{A}(ABAB)\color{#00A000}{B}\\
&=\color{#00A000}{AB}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying $A(BA-AB)B$ on the left by $A$ and the right by $B$ gives
$$AB-BA=A^2(BA-AB)B^2=A0B=0$$
as desired.

Answer (score 1):

We know $AA = I, BB= I, ABAB = I$. Thus $A^{-1} = A, B^{-1} = B$. Now $$ABAB = I \\ AB = IB^{-1}A^{1} = BA$$

Comment: If $A^2 = I$, then $A$ is invertible and its inverse is $A$.

Comment: From above: have not learnt inverses yet! Guess that's why I didn't think of this...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Is $BA$ the inverse of $AB$. How to check that?

Comment: Have not learnt inverses yet!

Answer (score 0):

$$BA=BAI=BA(ABAB)=B(AA)BAB=BIBAB=(BB)AB=IAB=AB$$

Answer (score 0):

$A,B$ belong to the group $GL_n(F),~(F$ being the field over which $A,B$ are defined$).$ So you may apply cancellation on $(AB)^2=A^2B^2.$